# What does "Where AOC requirements are redundant to AAC requirements, or more detailed, the AOC requirements will be followed." on Part 7 of CAR

Tags: regulations, caa-uk-regulations

Does it mean, The requirements for AOC are no longer useful to AAC, AOC will be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if the AOC is more detailed, or contains the same thing as the AAC, then whatever is written in the AOC should be used.